# Concern is not loading in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, activesupport-concern

I have a basic Rails application and I am trying to use concerns for drying models. Everything goes fine in the development environment, but when I try to upload the app to Heroku, it constantly gives me this error:

```
/app/app/models/address.rb:3:in `<class:Address>': uninitialized constant Address::Persistable (NameError)
```

I tried to disable eager loading, but it didn't help.

Here is my Address Model:

```
class Address < ApplicationRecord

  include Persistable

  belongs_to :city
  belongs_to :company

  validates :city_id, :human, :lat, :lng, presence: true
end
```

And here is the module that I named "persistable", located at `app/models/concerns/persistable.rb`

```
module Persistable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    scope :historical, -> { where(is_historical: true) }
    scope :deleted, -> { where(is_deleted: true) }
    default_scope { where(is_historical: false, is_deleted: false) }

    def delete
      update_attribute(:is_deleted, true)
    end

    def archive
      update_attribute(:is_historical, true)
    end

    def revive
      update_attribute(:is_historical, false)
      update_attribute(:is_deleted, false)
    end
  end
end
```

What I already did:

- tried to switch off eager loading
- tried to move the `Persistable` module out of the `concerns` directory
- tried to include the `concerns` path to the autoload configuration

Nothing worked, I still have this problem!

**UPDATE**

I did command form [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html) `rails r 'puts ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths'` to check autoload_paths and I got:

```
D:/work/rails/www/app/models/concerns
D:/work/rails/www/app/assets
D:/work/rails/www/app/channels
D:/work/rails/www/app/controllers
D:/work/rails/www/app/helpers
D:/work/rails/www/app/jobs
D:/work/rails/www/app/mailers
D:/work/rails/www/app/models
D:/work/rails/www/test/mailers/previews
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the problem was in Heroku server configuration. Seems like Heroku blocking constant name `Persistable`. Once I renamed every occurance of `Persistable` to `Archivable`, it just started to work.

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar issue with the same error message, but a different fix.

Running `spring stop` solved it for me.

When rails is having trouble autoloading, reseting spring is usually a good start.

Answer (score 0):

This should have given you a hint:

> uninitialized constant Address::Persistable (NameError)

It tries to locate the module within Address, for some reason. Be explicit and require top-level Persistable

```
class Address < ApplicationRecord

  include ::Persistable
```

Comment: Thanks! But error is still appears, in different form: ```/app/app/models/address.rb:3:in `<class:Address>': uninitialized constant Persistable (NameError)```. Where should I look?

Comment: @Max: seems that your autoload_paths is messed up somehow. I'd look into that now.

Comment: Hm, that is interesting. I am temporarily out of ideas. :)

Comment: Okay, I will answer this question if something will change, anyway thanks!

Comment: I posted an answer, solution was simple =)